# I have applied the same texture in to two cushions in Blender 3.0 and for some reason the scale is different on them, does anyone know why?

Tags: textures, scaling, materials

I have made two objects but the scale looks enormous on one when the material is the same on both...

[image]

I tried remaking the cushion with the bigger scale as I thought it had something to do with the unwrapping, that didn't fix it so now I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your material setup. What kind of mapping are you using? UVs or Generated Box mapping?
If it's UVs, you need to manually adjust the UVs of your model(s), to give them a similar texel density. You can learn more about UV Unwrapping [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv/introduction.html) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM)

If you're using "Generated" or "Object" instead of UVs for your texture mapping, you should apply the scale for both objects. In edit mode, press Ctrl+A then select "Scale". This should fix any shading issues related specifically to object scale.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the help. It was done via UV, I am still finding it difficult to completely understand but that video link you sent is really helpful :) Will need to absorb it a bit more...